# Requests lib changing characters to URL-encoded representation

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send a get request to an api that includes timestamps.  The URL is getting changed and instead of : %253A is inserted and I get a 500 error code.

```
url = 'https://www.fleetTrackingSimplicity.com/REST6/api/vehiclehistory/2'
start = '2020-12-01T00:00:00Z'
end = '2020-12-02T00:00:00Z'
param = {'startdate': start, 'enddate': end, 'count':'500'}

r_auth = str(a_json['TransactionId'])
headers2 = dict (Authorization = r_auth, Accept = 'application/json')
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers2, params=param)
```

When I print r.url I get https://www.fleettrackingsimplicity.com/REST6/api/vehiclehistory/2?startdate=2020-12-01T00%253A00%253A00Z&enddate=2020-12-02T00%253A00%253A00Z&count=500

Comment: Do you have api documentation?

Comment: I do, but it is a pdf document.  I do not have a link to it.

Comment: Paste the definition of endpoint you are using in question